# Which extension/skin Wikipedia uses from mobile? How can I mimic in my MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I've already tried a few times to understand which extension of MediaWiki is used by Wikipedia. Any hint?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Mobile_access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MinervaNeue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:MinervaNeue) skin and the [MobileFrontend](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileFrontend) extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask you an advice on where to search for help with mediawiki? I've opened a small wiki (http://tematichedigenere.com/) but every time I need to update or change something is a fight... Also if you have any advice I really appreciate.

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Project:Support_desk mainly. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Communication lists some other places.